# Adding to the the end of a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I am writing a method that adds an object to the end of a linked list. I know if I had

```
 LinkedList someList = new LinkedList();
```

I could very easily add it by just doing,

```
list.addLast(b);
```

But I am wondering how I could do it in this method?

```
private BookNode head;
private int size;

public void add(Book b) {
    BookNode n = new BookNode(b);
    BookNode p = head;

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        n = p.getNext();

    }

}
```

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a homework question. StackOverflow is not a solve-my-homework problem.

Comment: I have a test over linked lists next week and I need to have a good comprehesion of how they work.

Comment: Look up "Linked list" in Wikipedia.  It will tell you everything you want to know and  more.

Comment: I know what a linked list is. I'm not stupid. It is the coding part of the test I am getting ready for. Thanks for the useless comment dude.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by working out an example on paper on what exactly is happening when you pass a Book object to that method and the commenting out the code to really understand what is going on. Practicing the basics and gaining that understanding will really help you later on when you run into a more complicated linked list problem.